# React-Native Warning: unable to load source map

Tags: ios, react-native, source-maps

Just saw this warning working on a react-native app (ES6). The warning says:

```
Unable to load source map: "version" is a required argument.
```

It isn't clear to me where this is coming from and I was hoping someone could explain and/or tell me how to rectify. Doesn't prevent the app from working but I don't like ignoring stuff like this.

[image]

Comment: Can you post some code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create `.babelrc` file at root of the project folder like below:

```
{
  "presets": ["react-native"],
  "sourceMaps": false
}
```